# Can't log in using sa account for sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, authentication

I installed SQL Server 2008. During the install I set it to mixed mode authentication and set the password for what I assume is the `sa` account. In the configuration manager I set `tcp/ip` and `named pipes` to **enabled**.

When I open SQL Server Management Studio and try to log in - `username: sa, password: whatIjustsetintheinstall`, it fails with the error:

`Login failed for user sa. (error 18456). The error in Event Viewer is - Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: <local machine>].`

I know the password is right because I just set it. What am I doing wrong here? Is `sa` not the right user to be logging in with mixed mode? I've been reading through forum after forum but just cannot find anything that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This will soon get migrated to ServerFault but...]

It's entirely possible you mistyped the password twice for the sa account on install. I've done it. Try to log in with Windows Authentication to see if you can reset the sa password. If not, you will either have to hack your install or reinstall.

Comment: This is super dumb, but I tried sa with no password and that worked. I'm just going to write this off as "it's been a long day" and stop trying to understand. Thanks for your help!